# Separate small, large JFrame icons

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe

I have an icon I want to use for my JFrame, and it looks good in the Windows 7 taskbar, and in the alt-tab view, but it doesn't look so great resized to 16x16, in the top left corner of the window.

Is there a way to use an ico file with two icon files, or two png files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Window.setIconImages(List)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29).